# How to run xcode c++ program on another computer?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, release

I know this is a question that comes up a lot, but having tried a bunch of solutions on the web I am still at a loss! Apologies if it is trivial.

I have a very simple program, written in Xcode version 5.1.1

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::cout << "\nHello, World!\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I go to Product>>Scheme>>Edit Scheme and change Build Configuration to Release. I then build the program, and find an executable file (called 'HelloWorld') in the Products>>Release folder. I can run this program by double clicking, or by navigating to it through terminal and running in the usual way.

However, if I send it to another Mac it does not run. The program no longer has the executable icon, and just opens terminal (without printing anything) when I double click it.

The computer on which it was created is a Mac with Intel Core i7 processor and OS X 10.9.4. I've tried running it on two other machines: First Intel Core i7 OS X 10.9.4, second Intel Core Duo OS X 10.6.8.

I am very new to C++ coding, and am probably doing something simple wrong. Is my program linking to files that are only on my machine or something?

Thanks in advance for any help

Bob

Comment: Probably it does print hello world, but then it finishes execution and is closed.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Good point, this is very likely the case. OP may want to stick some sort of pausing/sleeping statement into the program, just to allows themselves to see it in action. If it _really_ isn't working (though it sounds like it is), I suppose it could be a 32/64-bit issue or something? I'm really not sure.

Comment: @DavidFrye "OP may want to stick some sort of pausing/sleeping statement into the program" - I would rather advise him to use the Terminal to run the "app", since it's really just a command line program.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: I was thinking of the "double click this icon" use case, but fair enough.

Comment: How do you `send` it to another Mac? Email? FTP? You may be losing the executable bit when sending it if it no longer has the executable icon. Try going in Terminal and setting the executable bit using `chmod +x /path/to/HelloWorld` then try running it again. If you run `ls -l HelloWorld` you need to see an `x` near the left side to show it is executable.

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to those who gave answers above - particularly Mark Setchell.

As suggested by Mark, the problem turned out to be the method of sending the program to another computer via e-mail. For some reason (which I assume has to do with virus protection) some of the properties were stripped when sending. I simply transferred the program via Dropbox and it worked fine.

I still haven't got it working on the older Intel Core Duo OS X 10.6.8 computer, but I assume this has to do with the 32bit vs. 64 bit difference.

Thanks again!

Bob